# VueJS click on 1 button and disable the remaining buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

so i have 3 buttons in a v-for loop with a click method in it.

I want to click on a button and disable the others, but also be able to click the active button and enable the other.

Thanks :)

'data': []

```
<div v-for="(index, value, key) in data.data">
    <button @click="onClick(index)">
        <div>{{ index.id }}</div>
    </button>
</div>

onClick(index) {//}
```

Comment: please provide a code example of what you have so far

Comment: @kfedorov91 done :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    buttons: [false, false, false]
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(index) {
      if (this.buttons.every(b => !b)) {
        this.buttons = this.buttons.map((b, i) => (i === index ? false : true));
      } else {
        this.buttons = this.buttons.map(b => false);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/bart0810/pen/zJXNXx

Comment: But the data loading is not like I want to.

Comment: What do you mean, data loading?

Comment: buttons: [false,false,false] ... I get my data in a json object where I loop through with the v-for. In my v-for I have multiple buttons, depending on how much objects they are. So I dont know how I can implement the buttons array in my code some how